# Is there a way of implementing the Strategy pattern using variadic templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, strategy-pattern

I would like to encapsulate different algorithms as strategies. All strategies would provide a single method potentially differing in the number and types of parameters.

```
template <typename... Arguments>
double price(Arguments... parameters)
```

The strategies should not be coded directly in the class using them. Is there a simple way of implementing the strategy design pattern using variadic templates? I'm also aware of "policy-based design" and I m trying to achieve something similar using variadic templates

Comment: Are you looking for run-time or compile-time polymorphism? The GoF Strategy pattern involves the former, but the term "strategy" has been become more fuzzy to also include the latter.

Comment: How do you expect this to work?  Assume you could legally accomplish this, how would a caller of `price(...)` know which arguments to provide, since they are unaware of the actual arguments ahead of time.

Comment: I was of thinking compile-time polymorphism, something equivalent to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design using variadic templates. I m just curious to find out if it s possible and also if it provides any advantages

Comment: I recommend showing what the "strategy pattern" is about. Not everyone has those design pattern names in their head and some use them differently.

Comment: Could you post example code that shows how you would like to use your interface?

Comment: Also I would like to understand how variadic templates and policy-based design fit together as described here: http://cppandbeyond.com/2011/06/21/session-announcement-ten-years-of-policy-based-design-and-counting Perhaps a better name for the post would have been policy-based design using variadic templates...

Comment: @BigLudinski do you want to teach us things? Do you want us to go and read stuff - homework? Or do you want help with your question :)

Comment: I need help with something that is not clear in my own head :) OK perhaps my question was not well formulated. Perhaps I should ve said "How do policy-based design and variadic templates fit together". Once again the following link suggests that policy-based design can be implemented using variadic templates: http://cppandbeyond.com/2011/06/21/session-announcement-ten-years-of-policy-based-design-and-counting/ Forget about the strategy pattern for the moment. In my case I want to be able to select a given algorithm at compile time as in: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean, you want to have strategies that require different arguments, that can be transparently forwarded by the user of the strategy, without it knowing about any of the actual parameters?

Demo (*contrived but illustrative, I hope*). See it live on **http://ideone.com/MExyx**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct StratA {
    enum gender { male, female, unknown };
    double price(std::string name, int age, gender g) const
    { return 42; }
};

struct StratB {
    double price(int age, int volume, double historic_rate) const
    { return (age*age*historic_rate)/volume; }
};

template <typename PricingStrategy=StratA>
struct SomeEngine
{
    template <typename... Args>
    void doSomethingInvolvingPricing(std::string logmessage,
            Args... args) // involving pricing
    {
        std::cout << logmessage << ": " << PricingStrategy().price(std::forward<Args>(args)...) << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    SomeEngine<>().doSomethingInvolvingPricing("default", "name", 18, StratA::female);
    SomeEngine<StratB>().doSomethingInvolvingPricing("overridden", 18, 3000, 4.5);
}
```

Output (also on [ideone](http://ideone.com/MExyx)):

```
default: 42
overridden: 0.486
```

Comment: Sehe it looks exactly like what I would like to do :) Let me try this out and come back to you with any questions...thanks! :)